# Bug with the text length when flagging a comment with "Something else"

Tags: bug, comment-flags, flag-dialog, character-limit

I found [three rude but useful comments from a single poster for this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388500/2985643) to the question [How to use unicode characters in Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388490/2985643). I haven't identified the user or the specific comments here because they are not relevant for this post, but they are easy to discover if you care.

The three comments were potentially useful since they were challenging the accuracy of a highly upvoted answer (421 votes), but all of them were also rude and condescending. I tried to flag the first comment using option *"Something else"* with the following text, which was 282 characters long:

> This comment is criticizing the accuracy of a highly upvoted question
> so it might be useful. However, part of it is also rude and
> condescending: "Over 300 incompetents so far have upvoted this advice.
> That's impressive.". Can the comment be retained, but without the
> offensive part?

Here's a screen shot immediately prior to submission, which displays the message *"218 characters left"*:

[image: Pre submission]

Submitting the comment resulted in the error *"Please enter at least 6 and no more than 200 characters"*, even though my comment had *"218 characters left"*:

[image: Post submission]

Once I reduced the comment to 196 characters it was submitted successfully.

> This comment is criticizing the accuracy of a highly upvoted question
> so it might be useful. However, part of it is also rude/condescending.
> Can the comment be retained without the offensive part?

So there are a couple of issues arising, since the error message (*"...no more than 200 characters"*) conflicts with the pre-submission advisory message (*"218 characters left"*):

- What is the *actual* text length limit when flagging a comment for *"Something else"*? 200 characters? Prior to submission it looks like the allowed length should be 500 characters (282 character comment + *"218 characters left"*).
- What is the *intended* maximum length of the *"Something else"* text box? 500? 200? Something else? Sometimes it's tricky to be *"as specific as possible"* with a text limit of just 200 characters.

Note that this post almost is a duplicate of the SE question [I cannot flag a comment as "Something else" with an explanation longer than 200 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383047)

Comment: [... increasing the mod flag comment max length to a limit of 500 from its previous 200 character count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383040/348196) --> [I cannot flag a comment as "Something else" with an explanation longer than 200 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383047/348196).

Comment: Actually, on closer examination this isn't a duplicate. That question is on SE, and is about increasing the text length for comments, but mine is about the _inconsistency of the messages_ when you post a comment > 200 chars. Also, [a mod answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383040) that _"This issue has been addressed by increasing the mod flag comment max length to a limit of 500 from its previous 200 character count"_, but that clearly isn't true on SO. (Or maybe part of the fix hasn't made it to SO yet?)

Comment: There are two links in my previous comment. The first one is about increasing the limit, and the second one is reporting an issue that the new logic doesn't work properly. This question is a cross-site duplicate of the _second_ one. But there's probably no need to close or delete it because there is no dupe target on _this_ site. I was just providing the links for reference.

Comment: Gotcha. I had missed that you had posted two links, and the second one really is an SE equivalent of my post. I'll leave this question alone, but add your second link to the question. I suspect the whole thing might resolve itself in the next few days. Also, I am not allowed to delete my question as a duplicate of an SE question.

Comment: Per a [CM comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383047/i-cannot-flag-a-comment-as-something-else-with-an-explanation-longer-than-200#comment1277506_383047) on '[I cannot flag a comment as "Something else" with an explanation longer than 200 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383047/271271)', I'm not adding a [tag:status-review] tag at this time. The CM stated that they will, for now, work on the issue under the original ticket.